# Stuck with proguard while migrating from Retrofit 2.0.0 beta4 to 2.0.1

Tags: android, performance, retrofit2, android-proguard

I was trying to migrate from Retrofit 2.0.0-beta4 to 2.0.1 but the proguard text shows a bug in it .
The for the text that i have added is:

> -dontwarn retrofit2.
>   -keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
>   -keepattributes Signature
>   -keepattributes Exceptions
>   -keepclasseswithmembers class * {@retrofit2.http.*;} **(line number 31)**

and the bug which i get when i try to make a release build is that the proguard text has something missing and the text is as follows :

**Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: proguard.ParseException: Expecting java type before ';' in line 31 of file '/Users/abc/Downloads/xyz/app/proguard-rules.pro'

:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED**

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.   java.io.IOException: proguard.ParseException: Expecting java type before ';' in line 31 of file '/Users/ABC/Downloads/XYZ/app/proguard-rules.pro'

Comment: I had the same problem and returned to 1.* retrofit. i think 2.* is still far from stable.

Comment: You have a typo on your first line. I believe it should be -dontwarn retrofit.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/blob/master/libraries/proguard-square-retrofit2.pro

```
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
```